# difference of two graphs in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have two multiDiGraph graphs in NetworkX. They have the same number of nodes and edges. but, the numbering of nodes are different. I used nx.is_isomorphic to compare them. The output is False. But, I think they are isomorphic. How can I find why they are not and what is the difference?

I can not compare the edges manually one by one. I found difference methods for the graphs that the node names are the same.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example as a fully reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find why ( two non-isomorphic graphs are not isomorphic )

There is no why.

Two graphs are isomorphic if there exists a mapping of the vertices in one graph to the other, that results in the list of edges being identical in both.

Suppose we search through every possible mapping and check if the edge lists are identical.  We find a mapping where the the edge lists are identical except for one missing edge.  Is the missing edge the 'why these are not isomorphic'?  Of course not! The next mapping might prove the graphs ARE isomorphic.  If they are not isomorphic, none of the multitude of failed mappings represents why they are not isomorphic.